# Regex that prohibits repetitions of two alternating numbers

Tags: regex

I want to make a regex to test repetitions like this

```
0101010101
2323232323
1313131313
4848484848
```

This is what I've done so far but it doesn't work

```
var noAlternateRepeatRegex = /^(?!.*\\d{2}\\d{2}|.*00|.*11|.*22)$/;
```

Can you tell me the regex that prohibits repetitions of two alternating numbers?

---

### **EDIT to address the request for clarification in the comments.**

I code in JavaScript to validate a phone number entered in an input field.

It is the JavaScript regex engine that is used.

This is my function.

```
function validatePhoneNumber() {
    var telephoneValue = telephoneInput.val();

    // Use a regular expression to check the 10-digit phone number
    var regex = /^\d{10}$/;

    // checks that the phone number does not contain a sequence of digits repeated more than 9 times, prohibiting the digits 0 to 9 from repeating more than 9 times.
    var noRepeatRegex = /^(?!.*(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)\1{9})/;

    // verifies that no sequence of two alternating digits is repeated more than 5 times in the telephone number.
    var noAlternateRepeatRegex = /^(?!.*\\d{2}\\d{2}|.*00|.*11|.*22)$/;

    if (!regex.test(telephoneValue) || !noRepeatRegex.test(telephoneValue) || !noAlternateRepeatRegex(telephoneValue)) {
        // code
        return;
    }

    // The phone number is valide
    // code
 }
```

I have not received any specific rules for doing this. My client asked me to ban the following numbers.

```
0101010101
0123456789
0102030405
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
```

I deduced that the rule is that one must prohibit

- All numbers are the same, like "1111111111".
- The numbers are consecutive in ascending or descending order, such as
  "0123456789".
- The numbers repeat in sequence, such as "0101010101", "0102030405",
  etc.

Comment: Try this: `/^(?!(\d\d)\1+$)\d+$/`

Comment: Is `2222222222` valid?

Comment: Try `^(?!(?:(\d)(\d|$)(?:\1\2|\1?$))+$)\d+$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2NoFWL/2).

Comment: If you only want an assertion preventing pairs of 2 different alternating numbers and the minimum amount of characters this applies to is 4, then perhaps `^(?!(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?:\1\2)+$)` https://regex101.com/r/UBAfTl/1 If you also do not want to match just `12` then change the quantifier to `^(?!(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?:\1\2)*$)`

Comment: Or a bit simpler: `/^(?!((\d)(?!\2)\d)\1+$)\d+$/`

Comment: @anubhava Awesome refactoring :-)

Comment: No. Just no. Just because you *can* do something with a regex doesn't mean you should. Just split your number into two-character strings and make sure each consecutive pair isn't duplicative of the previous one.

Comment: I'm voting to close until you provide more detail. You have too many undefined edge cases. For example `0101010101` has at least *three* repeating sequences: `01`, `10`, and `0101`. You also haven't defined the business rules for "repeating numbers," nor have you defined whether numbers like `0000000000` is a repeating or how that should be parsed. You also haven't defined a language or regex engine, and although on might assume JavaScript based on your use of `var` we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: I've edited my question to answer the questions in the comments.

Comment: What you said is key: "I have not received any specific rules for doing this". Your client is the boss - verify with them before assuming they want certain rules. It could be likely that they only want to ban the specific list and nothing else. If you assume a rule when none was intended, that is a bug, and you risk of angering the client.

Answer (score 1):

If the string matches the following regular expression there exists a pair of  successive characters that is not the same as the following pair of successive characters, meaning that the string is not comprised exclusively of a repeating pair of characters.

```
(..)(?!\1)..
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5HWwAI/1)

I have assumed that it is known that the string is comprised exclusively of digits.

Comment: Readers: help me out. If you see a problem with my answer please tell me what it is.

Comment: Not being the downvoter I think the question is mostly unclear yet. OP writes from *prohibits **repetitions** of **two alternating** numbers* but in his attempted regex he lists options like e.g. `00` which are two same numbers causing confusion. Your regex looks like a good idea. Only thing maybe why to put this into a lookahead. I mean why not just [`(..)(?!\1)..`](https://regex101.com/r/hdhvM8/1) which would be sufficient for the check, wouldn't it. Generally I noticed the air almost became for cutting here lately.

Comment: @bobblebubble, thanks, I implemented your suggestion. I’m a dummy for having missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is an academic question on regular expressions, or an absolute requirement to use them,  I would opt for an imperative solution as the parsing is trivial.  And as is here, custom implementations can be more efficient. This is written in Java.

- It first checks if the String is odd or length of two.  If either, it can't be a repeating digraph so return true.
- Return true if the two digraphs are different, or the two digits of one are the same.
- if the loop finishes, return false.

```
Predicate<String> isValid = str -> {
    if ((str.length() & 1) == 1 || str.length() == 2) {
        return true; // is odd or single digraph
    }
    String p1 = str.substring(0, 2);
    for (int i = 2; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
        String p2 = str.substring(i, i + 2);
        if (!p1.equals(p2) || p1.charAt(0) == p1.charAt(1)) {
            return true;
        }
        p1 = p2;
    }
    return false;
};

String[] tests = {"01","010","01010101","23232323","44444444",
                    "22332233","01220123","13132313","48484848"};
for (String str : tests) {
    System.out.printf("%-8s --> %s%n", str,
            isValid.test(str) ? "Valid." : "Not valid.");
}
```

prints

```
01       --> Valid.
010      --> Valid.
01010101 --> Not valid.
23232323 --> Not valid.
44444444 --> Valid.
22332233 --> Valid.
01220123 --> Valid.
13132313 --> Valid.
48484848 --> Not valid.
```